# Node Transform stream not sending output to pipe?

Tags: node.js, stream

## What I'm Working On

I'm attempting to write a Transform stream that will be used as part of a process that reads data from an HTTP API (Salesforce), transforms each resource into a standard internal data structure, and then sends the transformed data to be indexed by Elasticsearch.

## My Problem

I've written a simple Transform stream, but it appears to be swallowing data, instead of passing it through.

**Here's my class `AdapterStream`**

```
const { Transform } = require('stream')

class AdapterStream extends Transform {
  constructor (adapter) {
    super({objectMode: true})
    // adapter is a function that contains the transform logic
    this.adapter = adapter
  }

  _transform (chunk, _encoding, callback) {
    this.push(this.adapter(chunk))
    callback()
  }
}

module.exports = AdapterStream
```

**Here's how I'm using it**

```
// query is an EventEmitter (https://jsforce.github.io/document/#query)
query.run({autoFetch: true, maxFetch: 10})
     .pipe(transform)
     .pipe(process.stdout)
```

**What I expect to happen**

I expect to see the transformed data in my terminal window.

**What is actually happening**

Nothing is printed in my terminal window

## Things I've Tried

**Writing to a file**

```
query.run({autoFetch: true, maxFetch: 10})
     .pipe(transform)
     .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./test.json'))
```

This creates the file `./test.json` as expected, but it is empty.

**Subscribing to events**

```
query.run({autoFetch: true, maxFetch: 10})
     .pipe(transform)

transform.on('readable', () => { console.log(transform.read()) })
```

This does what I expected `.pipe(process.stdout)` to do: print the transformed records to the console.

My question is, why doesn't `pipe()` do what I'm expecting it to do? There must be something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: The node documentation points to what is probably the cause of my problem: `Note: Care must be taken when using Transform streams in that data written to the stream can cause the Writable side of the stream to become paused if the output on the Readable side is not consumed.`
[stream_implementing_a_transform_stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream). I'm not sure what exactly that means for me though

Comment: Would you mind to provide a minimal example of a query that I can actually run to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You want to return the data as the second parameter to the callback. Like below.

```
const { Transform } = require('stream')

class AdapterStream extends Transform {
  constructor (adapter) {
    super({objectMode: true})
    // adapter is a function that contains the transform logic
    this.adapter = adapter
  }

  transform (chunk, _encoding, callback) {
    callback(null, this.adapter(chunk))
  }
}
```